# $this object in loaded template with angular

Tags: php, html, angularjs, codeigniter

I'm trying to implement some ACL stuff in my Codigniter+AngularJs page.
I'm using ng-route, so i have that line in my Master-View page:

```
  <div ng-view></div>
```

I'm using ion-auth library for helping in ACL realisation.

This is my controller:

```
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->database();
    $this->load->library(['ion_auth', 'form_validation']);
    $this->load->helper(['url', 'language']);
    $this->lang->load('auth');
}

public function index()
{
    if (!$this->ion_auth->logged_in())
    {
        // redirect them to the login page
        redirect('/login', 'refresh');
    }
    else
    $this->load->view('master_view');
}
```

Here is my ng-route using:

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", ["ngRoute","bw.paging"]);
app.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when("/", {
        templateUrl : "/app/templates/cars_list.php",   
    controller: "CarsController"
    })
});
```

When i'm trying to use ion auth's function in my master-view it works fine:

```
<?php if($this->ion_auth->in_group('admin')):?>
<a class="nav-item nav-link" href="index.php#!/list">Users</a>
<?php endif;?>
```

But when i try that line in loaded template (cars_list.php) it does nothing.
Please,help me.How could i use $this in my template? TIA!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use `$this` inside template instead you can do like this.

```
public function index()
{
    if (!$this->ion_auth->logged_in())
    {
        // redirect them to the login page
        redirect('/login', 'refresh');
    }
    else{
        $data = [];
        $data["allowed"] = $this->ion_auth->in_group('admin');
        $this->load->view('master_view',$data);
    }
}
```

In view

```
<?php if($allowed):?>
<a class="nav-item nav-link" href="index.php#!/list">Users</a>
<?php endif;?>
```

Comment: Got that! Thanks, sir.